# Is possible to use SSL in Odoo with NginX avoiding the standard ports (80 and 443)?

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, odoo-8, odoo

Following [this tutorial](http://www.schenkels.nl/2014/12/reverse-proxy-with-odoo-8-nginx-ubuntu-14-04-lts/) I configured my Nginx like this:

```
upstream odoo8 {
    server 127.0.0.1:8069 weight=1 fail_timeout=0;
}

upstream odoo8-im {
    server 127.0.0.1:8072 weight=1 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    # server port and name (instead of 443 port)
    listen 22443;
    server_name _;

    # Specifies the maximum accepted body size of a client request,
    # as indicated by the request header Content-Length.
    client_max_body_size 2000m;

    # add ssl specific settings
    keepalive_timeout 60;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate        /etc/ssl/nginx/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/nginx/server.key;

    error_page 497 https://$host:22443$request_uri;

    # limit ciphers
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!ADH:!MD5;
    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    # increase proxy buffer to handle some Odoo web requests
    proxy_buffers 16 64k;
    proxy_buffer_size 128k;

    # general proxy settings
    # force timeouts if the backend dies
    proxy_connect_timeout 3600s;
    proxy_send_timeout 3600s;
    proxy_read_timeout 3600s;
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503;

    # set headers
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    # Let the Odoo web service know that we’re using HTTPS, otherwise
    # it will generate URL using http:// and not https://
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

    # by default, do not forward anything
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_buffering off;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://odoo8;
    }

    location /longpolling {
        proxy_pass http://odoo8-im;
    }

    # cache some static data in memory for 60mins.
    # under heavy load this should relieve stress on the Odoo web interface a bit.
    location /web/static/ {
        proxy_cache_valid 200 60m;
        proxy_buffering on;
        expires 864000;
        proxy_pass http://odoo8;
    }
}
```

And I have this ports in my Odoo configuration

```
longpolling_port = 8072
xmlrpc_port = 8069
xmlrpcs_port = 22443
proxy_mode = True
```

When I load `https://my_domain:22443/web/database/selector` in the browser it loads well. But when I choose a database or I make any action, the address loses the `https` and the port, so it's loaded through the port 80. Then I would need to add this to the NginX configuration and the port 80 should be open

```
## http redirects to https ##
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;

    # Strict Transport Security
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=2592000;
    rewrite ^/.*$ https://$host:22443$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

Is there a way to avoid this redirection? Like that I could keep the port 80 closed in order to avoid spoofing

**Update**

I can open the login screen with the address `https://my_domain:22443/web/login?db=dabatase_name` and I can work well inside, but if I log out in order to choose another database in the droplist, it loses again the port and the ssl

Comment: Never used odoo but have you enabled proxy mode so that the site generates links based on the `X-Forwarded-Proto` you are setting? https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/cmdline.html#cmdoption-odoo.py--proxy-mode

Comment: Thank you Joe Doherty for the comment. But I changed my configuration to `proxy_mode = True` and I got the same result

Comment: So the links themselves in odoo are showing as HTTP? The problem is there and not with Nginx. Odoo needs to know that it has to generate URLs for the port otherwise links will always go to the wrong location.

Comment: If I log in one databse everything works fine because the parameter `web.base.url` is right: `https://my_domain:22443`. The problem is when I log out because I don't have that parameter because I am not logged in any database. How can I tell to Odoo: "use always this address"?

Comment: I updated my answer with a temporary solution that I found

Comment: For future reference, what finally did the trick for me was this line:
`error_page 497 https://$host:22443$request_uri;`

Answer (score -1):

Please, try to use this construction:

```
## http redirects to https ##
server
{
listen 80;
server_name _;
if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = 'http')
    {
    return 301 https://my_domain.com$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you don't understand my question. If I do what you suggest I would need to open the port 80. And that's the thing I want to avoid